# RN App won't running when updated to the React native latest version

Tags: react-native

I just upgrade my application to React Native latest version 0.61.5 but it makes my app won't open on the android emulator or devices. When it's running the app will be closed automatically.

How to fix it?

This is the react native info :

Node: 10.16.0
Yarn: 1.19.1
npm: 6.9.0
react: 16.9.0 
react-native: 0.61.5

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide precise information on what errors or any stack trace you are getting. Also, your research would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be crashing somewhere, try to check logs and post here if required.

Comment: try giving errrs and also from which version of RN are you upgrading to 0.61.5